# MobileFirst 7.0 When uploading an app in server farm mode, "Unresponsive" errors are received

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, rhel, mobilefirst-server

Environment details:
OS RHEL 6.8 64bits
IBM MobileFirst Platform Server Version - 7.0.0.00.20160526-2153
Project WAR Version - 7.0.0.00.20161114-0240
Application Version - 7.0.0.00.20160526-2153
IBM Websphere Liberty Verison - 8.5.5.4
Java - IBM JRE 1.7.0

Created a farm configuration following [IBM Knowledge Center MobileFirst 7.0 Configure Farm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_server_farm_setup.html) with uniques values for jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.serverid",farm_member_1 and farm_member_2.
At start, both servers show these into the messages.log:

```
[1/8/17 18:53:14:313 CST] 00000034 SystemErr R 1111  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-10] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2

[1/8/17 18:53:14:315 CST] 00000034 SystemErr R 1113  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-10] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10053 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.17.29).

[1/8/17 18:53:14:364 CST] 00000034 SystemErr R 1162  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-10] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
```

Almost every time an app is upload to the runtime, server 2 (farm_member_2) becomes unresponsive (Web console Home-->Runtime-->Server Farm Nodes).When that occurs, the server 2 is updating all the resources, like it was rebooting , loading all the apps and adapters from the runtime. Once finished to load all the apps, these error is shown again:

```
[1/9/17 1:43:19:868 CST] 00000b05 com.ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.ManagementMXBeanImpl             I runtime01: server01///10.77.230.146: 2017-01-09T07:43:19.850Z: Transaction handler reset

[1/9/17 1:43:19:869 CST] 0000005e com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter            I FWLSE0273I: Set sync required to 'false' [project runtime01]

[1/9/17 1:43:19:872 CST] 00000a86 SystemErr R 16601596  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-1589] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.

[1/9/17 1:43:19:880 CST] 00000a86 SystemErr R 16601604  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-1589] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
```

Is that a common thing with this type of configuration? If not,any ideas on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

These are warnings and can be safely ignored. These are logged by OpenJPA packages.

Comment: what about the unresponsive status of the servers, is that a normal behavior?